# Resetting the admin password for an application

Tags: passwords

We have a enterprise application dealing with data. We have one super user (admin) that has the highest level of privileges. The application is not opensource. If some customer has forgotten the password then we request them to send us the metadata and we reset it. Is this the right way? We know that many db vendors provide a way to reset the admin or the super user password. What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to provide a script seperate from the application which modifies the database store and resets the password of the user to one of the client's choosing (e.g. password given as argument). You should advise your clients to restrict access to the script at the operating system level to ensure no unauthorized access can occur. You can also advise your clients to perform auditing on the script's execution.

Comment: Well users should never have access to the physical machine where the application is running on. If they have access to the application directly (binaries) they can extract all information anyways.